# Unity Engine: How to change mointor/desktop resolution in 4.5.3 and higher

Tags: unity, resolution

As of unity 4.5.3, Screen.SetResolution and the Unity Resolution Display Dialog, by default, no longer change the monitor/desktop resolution. Instead, it only changes the render target resolution for the game. This means that if you run a 1024x768 resolution on a widescreen monitor, your cursor can travel into the letterboxed area, outside of the window bounds, even when running in full screen mode. This is not the desired behaviour for our game.

This was described in the [Unity 4.5.3 release notes](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.5.3):

**"Windows Player: The default full-screen mode no longer changes the desktop resolution, so things like IME text input work."**

I would like to *actually* change the desktop resolution. The change log suggests there is some non-default full-screen mode that will actually change the desktop resolution... How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's under

PlayerSettings>
Settings for Pc, Mac and Linux standalone>
StandAlone Player Options>
D3D9 Fullscreenmode
and D3D11 Fullscreenmode

But I find it kinda buggy;